# Override Flask Admin save new row in table

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

How would I be able to override and add some extra code when creating a new row in a table via the Admin panel in Flask?
For example: User enters info for a new row in the 'Post' table and clicks save. I want to add some code to automate a process with that new row information.

Answer (score 5):

You can override the methods [`on_model_change`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.on_model_change) to perform actions before saving/updating a new model,  or [`after_model_change`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.after_model_change) to do something after, obviously. 
You can inherit from the class `BaseModelView` or `ModelView` if you are using Flask-SqlAchemy.

In every cases, 3 arguments are provided to play with : the `form` used by the view, the new/updated `model` and the flag `is_created` to know if the model is new (`True`) or updated.

You can defined the model view like below :

```
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class PostView(ModelView):

    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        print(form, model, is_created)

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        print(form, model, is_created)

admin = Admin(template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session, name='Posts'))
```

---

Note : You have access to similar methods for the deleting part with `on_model_delete` and `after_model_delete`, except you only have the model given as argument.

Comment: This does not work for me at all. I am also getting an error with 'NoteView'

Comment: You didn't provide any code to know the name of the class, you must change this example to match your own classes.

Comment: Eventually got it :). Without NoteView